# Why does for (var i in null_object) enter the loop body more than zero times?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save and load a JavaScript object of the `{'foo':123}` type in localStorage. I have hit a strange behaviour.

```
localStorage .setItem ('names', null);

alert ("names is:" + localStorage .getItem ('names'));

for (var n in localStorage .getItem ('names'))
{
    alert ("#" + n + "#");
}
```

This gives the following alerts

```
names is:null
#0#
#1#
#2#
#3#
```

Surely this shouldn't happen. I have tested this on Firefox. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage` can only store strings. That means when you're calling `.setItem()`:

```
localStorage.setItem('names', null);
```

the `null` is converted to string `"null"`. Therefore it's the same as:

```
localStorage.setItem('names', "null");
```

That means you're looping over string, not over `null`.